# Fortran initialization

Tags: fortran

Is there a difference between initialization with declaration versus simple initialization?
For example

```
recursive function foo(x) result (f)
                   real :: x, y = 0
                   real :: f    
                   ...
end function
!versus
recursive function foo(x) result (f)
        real :: x, y 
        real :: f 
        y = 0 
        ...          
end function
```

Comment: You asked the same question on comp.lang.fortran.  See the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference!

The following code implicitly sets the `save` attribute for variable `y`.
This implies that it will only be set to 0 in the *first call* to the function and it retains its value from the previous call for the next call.

```
recursive function foo(x) result (f)
                   real :: x, y = 0
                   real :: f    
                   ...
end function
```

In comparison the other code sets `y` to 0 in *each* call.

```
recursive function foo(x) result (f)
        real :: x, y 
        real :: f 
        y = 0 
        ...          
end function
```

Comment: I thought it was something like that! Thanks